# List view generating duplicates data and how to connect to devices when click from list view

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-bluetooth

I have a problem regarding `listviews` where whenever I search for Bluetooth device it will display the list of available devices as usual, but on second click, it will generate duplicates as the results from the first scan still stays, so how do I get rid of the first scan results every time the user clicks the button to scan, and connect to the Bluetooth device when the end-user clicks on the address or name of the devices.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
public class BTReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            var application = context.ApplicationContext;
            string action = intent.Action;
            if (action == BluetoothDevice.ActionFound)
            {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice) as BluetoothDevice;
                devices.Add(new Devices(device.Name, device.Address));

                Devices item = list.First(d => d.name == device.Name);

                //if devices does not exist in the list, add it in
                if (item != null)
                {
                    return;
                }


                aadapter = new CustomAdapter(_instance, devices);
                availableList.Adapter = aadapter;
                aadapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

                Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, device.Name, ToastLength.Long);
                toast.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Device.cs**

```
public class Devices
{
    string _name;
    string _address;

    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }
    public string Address { get { return _address; } set { _address = value; } }

    public Devices(string name, string address)
    {
        Name = name;
        Address = address;
    }
}
```

**BTDevice.cs** aka the Custom Adapter I have created

```
public class CustomAdapter : BaseAdapter<Devices>
{
    private ObservableCollection<Devices> _devices;
    private Activity _context;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, ObservableCollection<Devices> devices) : base()
    {
        _context = context;
        _devices = devices;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var device = _devices[position];

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = ((Activity)_context).LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.listView, null);

        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textName).Text = device.Name;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textAddress).Text = device.Address;

        return view;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return _devices.Count; }
    }

    public override Devices this[int position]
    {
        get { return _devices[position]; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should clear devices before you add new things to it.
Something like ..

```
clear(devices)
devices.add(newdevice)
```

Comment: right now I have an error with list, you have any idea about it?

Comment: The name 'list' does not exist in the current context, the things is im not sure what list should i use because there error for each of it

Comment: Its just a sudo code. if you have a list defined and if you keep adding things to it without replacing or clearing it , you will have duplicated items.

Comment: you keep adding device to a list of "devices"

Comment: alright i got the errors solved, now leads to my second questions, how do I connect to it when I clicked the device name or address